# Converted ArcMap to KML Layer doesn't scale in Google Earth

Tags: arcgis-desktop, kml, convert, google-earth

I converted an ArcMap layer to KML and exported to Google Earth.  I had set the Layer Output Scale to '1' during conversion, however when I open in Google Earth, the layer does not scale as I zoom in.  Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure what you're expecting to happen in GE, but give a read of the scale parameter help here: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/map-to-kml.htm  -- the scale parameter essentially says make KML as if this was the viewing scale in ArcMap.

Comment: You'll have to excuse me because I am a beginner, but I was expecting that the layer would retain it's resolution at varying altitudes as it does in ArcMap.  Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: Short answer is no, the tool isn't going to output KML in this way. The longer answer (which I could be wrong about) is I dont know that GE even supports this unless the data is coming from a service.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @KHibma:

> Not sure what you're expecting to happen in GE, but give a read of the
>   scale parameter help here:
>   http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/map-to-kml.htm
>   -- the scale parameter essentially says make KML as if this was the viewing scale in ArcMap.

and

> Short answer is no, the tool isn't going to output KML in this way.
>   The longer answer (which I could be wrong about) is I dont know that
>   GE even supports this unless the data is coming from a service.